# Angular not pushing form data to array

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a simple messaging app. Without reloading the page, I want to push whatever the user writes to an array as well as db and then *ngFor that array to the page. I appreciate any help!

```
  <div id="messageBody" *ngFor="let message of messageInfo">

    <ul class="chatBox">

      <li [ngClass]="[message.creator._id === this.user ? 'me' : 'him']" id="timeStamp"> <span
          id="messageStats">{{message.creator.name}}<br>{{message.creationDate | date: 'medium'}}</span><br><br>
        {{message.message}}</li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <div id="messageBody" *ngIf="replying && messageSent">

    <div id="chatBoxContainer">

      <ul class="chatBox" *ngFor="let post of this.currentPosts">

        <li class="me" id="timeStamp"> <span id="messageStats"> Your Reply
            <br>{{post.replySentTimeStamp | date: 'medium'}}</span><br> <br> {{post.replyMessage}}</li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </div>
```

message.component.ts

```
 sendReplyMessage(form: NgForm) {

    if (form.invalid) {
      return;
    }

 let currentMessages = [];
form.value.replySentTimeStamp = Date.now();
currentMessages.push(...[{timeStamp: Date.now(), message: form.value.message}]);
this.replyMessage = "";


    this.replying = true;
    this.messageSent = true;
    this.creationDate = new Date();
    this.toastr.success('Message Sent');
    this.replySentTimeStamp = new Date();


    this.messagingService.replyToMessage(this.name, this.replyMessage, this.creationDate, this.lastSenderId, this.subject, this.messageTrackingIdResponse);

  }
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you're augmenting `messageInfo` which is what's being iterated in the template. Is this a message app across devices or just local?  If not just local, what's `messagingService`?  Need some more info.

Comment: messagingService is sending the data to mongodb. It's not relevant to the current issue. I'm trying to push the values locally to an array without performing API call then ngFor the values onto the page.

Comment: Ok. You're still not pushing anything into `messageInfo` which is what you're iterating over in the template. Simple example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ign9y).

Comment: Thanks Phix! That example helped me understand my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think we would benefit from having some more information as to what happens after the "this.messagingService.replyToMessage(....."

If it returns back the message, then you would want to insert that message into your messageInfo array. Then you would be able to see it in your for loop. So if your messagingService returns back the message, then you would want something like:

"this.messageInfo.push(this.messagingService.replyToMessage(...."

However, if your service is making an http request and expecting back a response from the API with the message in it, then you would want to add a subscription to the end of that line, to listed for the response and then add the message to the messageInfo array:

this.messagingService.replyToMessage(this.name, this.replyMessage, this.creationDate, this.lastSenderId, this.subject, this.messageTrackingIdResponse).subscribe(res => { this.messageInfo.push(res.body);}).

something like that. But without knowing what you are sending and what you are receiving back, there is not much else I can think of to help. This is just some general info. Good luck!

Comment: messagingService.replyToMessage is a POST to send message to mongodb. I was trying to be more efficient since I'm using a GET on the page with an ngFor to spit out all the messages kind of like an sms app. I want to push any messages the user sends to a local array that can spit out the additional messages onto the page continuing where the GET call left off when the page loaded without doing another GET